# Get contents of a .txt file and loop the result

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have a text file which lists images like so:

```
images/0.png
images/1.png
images/2.png
```

My question is do i still need to json_encode the data in the text file ? Aka rather than storing raw text in my text file, only store a json_encoded version and request it that way instead, or is it sufficient to grab raw text like shown above?

Comment: I can't think of a reason why loading it as raw text is a bad thing, actually converting this to JSON and parsing it seems to me like an overhead, but I might be missing something...

Comment: Well when i tried to do it i could only get the first line, not the entire contents of the file.

Comment: @Dave how did you determine that it was only first line?

Comment: I console.log'd the result and only got `images/0.png`

Comment: how did you request the data? how was this request processed server-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off encoding the text (as you put it) in JSON (or XML) and reading it in. That way your dealing with predefined objects and predefined methods for handling content instead of having to write a bunch of code yourself to parse the data out.

You also will be taking a standard approach to defining your data. This will allow you to use it in other ways and with other types of applications should the need ever arise.

Comment: You should also consider scalability. What happens if you decide you want to group your image types and only grab UI images as opposed to background images? Or what if you decided you want to add some other type of meta data for your photos like titles, tags, or descriptions? Or what if you want to add something besides photos to your data file?

You get far more capability and easier scalability with JSON than you do with a simple flat file.

Comment: So you suggest i create a json_encode data style and save that to a text file ?

Comment: Yeah. Just find a simple example on the web [like this](http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp), modify it to your needs, and save it as a ".txt" file. When you read the JSON in with jQuery or whatever you will easily be able to loop it, access it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to JSON encode it. I would as a personal preference. But you can just split the string by line break characters.

```
  var images = data.split("\n");
```